# Hide columns using JComboBox

Tags: java, oop, jtable, jcombobox

How can I hide columns using the jComboBox. What I want to do is that when I select an item in the jComboBox, it will display the specific column I have selected in the jTable

Comment: You are asking two questions here, please only focus on one at a time, and show your relevant code. Hint: 1) Add an action listener to the JCombo box to do something when a selection is made (refer to one of the many tutorials on the web, or similar question on this site). 2) Get the selected item name and use that to edit the JTable TableModel as normal (refer to one of the many tutorials on the web, or similar question on this site)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Controlling which columns get displayed is the job of a [TableColumnModel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#getColumnModel()).  Note that if you are only displaying one column, you shouldn’t be using a JTable at all;  you should be using a JList.